# I need a query to delete a value in table if value is older than 4 months please look at details

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, qtsql

I have a EmailID_tbl  that has email address of the users I have got request to "remove emails from EmailID_tbl if last login date for user is within the past 4 months."

Comment: What details are there to look at?

Comment: Should that request actually say "remove email from EmailID_tbl if last login date for user is older than 4 months"?  As it is, that would indicate that you would keep users who haven't logged on, but you would remove users that are active

Comment: I have a EmailID_tbl that has email address of the users I have got request to "remove emails from EmailID_tbl if last login date for user is within the past 4 months." how to delete emails that are older than 4 months in the EmailID_tbl?

Comment: This question does not show any research effort.

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: I'd like to suggest you update your question and include the TSQL you've attempted, and which failed to produce the desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that these are in the same table, you could just use a WHERE clause to determine what needs to be deleted via the [`DATEADD()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) function to subtract the appropriate number of months from [`GETDATE()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188383.aspx), which would yield the current date :

```
-- This would delete every record in your table with LastLoginDates 
DELETE 
  FROM EmailID_tbl
 WHERE LastLoginDate < DATEADD(month,-4,GETDATE())
```

Comment: I think you mean to use GETDATE. NOW is not a t-sql function.

Comment: Yes, that's right. Confused a bit of MySQL with SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a query that will do it:

```
DELETE
FROM EmailID_tbl
WHERE LastLoginDate <= DATEADD(mm, -4, GETDATE())
```

Change `LastLoginDate` to the actual name within your table which indicates the last login date, and change `<=` to `>=` if you actually mean to delete more active users instead of more inactive users.